# Simple, but can't find: syntax to work with member variables of STL queues with type class

Tags: c++, class, stl, queue

This question is homework help; I didn't see something against the rules about that.

This is my function:

```
void display_queue(queue<cat> original_queue) 
{                       
  int dummy_integer;
  queue<cat> dummy_queue;       
  cout << endl << "The queue contains: " << endl;

  //reads out the first q while moving values to second q
  while (!original_queue.empty())
  {
    cout << ' ' << original_queue.front().ears;
    dummy_integer = original_queue.front().ears;
    original_queue.pop();
    dummy_queue.push(dummy_integer).ears;
  }

  //put the values from q2 back to q1
  while (!dummy_queue.empty())
  {
    dummy_integer = dummy_queue.front().ears;
    dummy_queue.pop();
    original_queue.push(dummy_integer).ears;
  }

}
```

This is a stripped-down, renamed model of a function in my much larger program, which is to simulate the process management aspect of a kernel. While I can successfully display the contents of my queue when it is a queue, I haven't come across the syntax when it's a class within those angle brackets.

My incorrect syntax is in the lines where I am trying to `.push` and I feel like I've tried all possible options, but obviously that's false and I'm just fritzing.

Does anyone know exactly how to write it?

Comment: `std::queue::push` is a `void` member function. That means it doesn't return anything. You certainly cannot access an `ears` member from void.

Comment: Those angle brackets mean it's a template.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh, duh. So that means that what John Kugelman writes below (about using the constructor) seems to be the only way that I can do it using the STL queue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a constructor `cat::cat(int)`, you can add a new `cat` object to the queue with:

```
dummy_queue.push(cat(dummy_integer));
```

However, a larger question is whether you need to do all of this item shuffling at all. The STL `queue` template has an artificial limitation in not exposing a way to iterate over its items. Consider using `deque` instead, which will let you iterate over the queue without having to remove and re-insert its contents.

```
void display_queue(const deque<cat> &queue) 
{
    cout << endl << "The queue contains: " << endl;

    while (deque<cat>::const_iterator cat = queue.begin(); cat != queue.end(); ++cat)
    {
        cout << ' ' << cat->ears;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could at least simplify your code a bit by simply iterating over a copy of the original queue. You wouldn't need to restore the original queue if you destroy a copy of it.

That would also let you make a nice optimization and change the parameter to a `const queue &`. This will pass the original queue from the caller as a reference instead of copying it.

```
void display_queue(const queue<cat> &original_queue) 
{
    queue<cat> queue_copy(original_queue);       
    cout << endl << "The queue contains: " << endl;

    while (!queue_copy.empty())
    {
        cout << ' ' << queue_copy.front().ears;
        queue_copy.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point, having put nearly two dozen hours into this project, I'm loathe to change most of my queues into dequeues, although I suppose a few CTRL+H's might end up being all it takes. However, what you say about using the constructor seems to be exactly what I have to do, since as Juanchopanza says, I can't return a value with a push function. I think I'm going to end up doing what you say about iterating over the copy. That's a pretty sleek and clever way of handling the display. Much appreciated!